# Ubuntu-Emulator will not install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-emulator

When I try to install `ubuntu-emulator` through terminal I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-emulator : Depends: ubuntu-emulator-runtime
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have no broken packages! It acts like ubuntu-emulator-runtime has been taken off the servers.

It will not install through the `Ubuntu-SDK` either.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: go to software center and enable all the extra repos like universe multiverse backports etc

Comment: specifically, you need multiverse http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-emulator-runtime

Comment: and for ubuntu-emulator you need universe http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-emulator&searchon=names

Comment: Thanks for your help here, I think that enabling the extras worked! It is now creating an instance so it looks hopeful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, go to software center, click edit, click software sources, enable the multiverse and universe repositories.

then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator-runtime
```

if it installs fine, run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
```

---

That should fix it, however,

if error then run:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

if libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 "cannot be found" then run this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
```

or possibly

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

but I don't think this version (i386) is actually needed because the base package requires  multiarch support so it's probably the right one to begin with but if not then here you go.

because libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic provides libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

if that installs fine, run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator-runtime
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
```

read the error from that output and go from there. Install this stuff one by one and if it asks for a specific version like 1.0.5 then sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator-runtime=1.0.5 for example.

Comment: i almost forgot, you must run apt-get update after you add i386 architecture

Comment: @Daniel yes I checked and ubuntu-emulator-runtime is  in the multiverse repository and ubuntu-emulator is in universe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. You can find the answer in the comments after my question. I will marked this as solved.